# Ошибка: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Я получаю такую ошибку при компиляции проекта:

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
> private final myapp.data.VkPerson.VkCity city = null;

Я видел подобное в случае если пытаются сохранить в Room-базу List, но у меня не лист.
Что можно сделать, чтобы сохранять этот VkCity? он же какбы сам - объект. Или я что-то путаю?
Я сделал объект VkPerson с такой структурой потому, что получаю response от API в такой форме.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

VkPerson object:

```
@Entity(tableName = "people")
@Parcelize
data class VkPerson(

    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    val lastName: String?,
    @SerializedName("photo_200_orig")
    val photo: String?,
    val domain: String?,
    val city: VkCity?

) : Parcelable {

    @Parcelize
    data class VkCity(
        val title: String?
    ) : Parcelable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил без TypeConvertera, вписал аннотацию @Embedded над `val city: VkCity`, и все собралось успешно:

```
@Parcelize
data class VkPerson(

    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    val lastName: String?,
    @SerializedName("photo_200_orig")
    val photo: String?,
    val domain: String?,
    @Embedded
    val city: VkCity?

) : Parcelable {

    @Parcelize
    data class VkCity(
        val title: String?
    ) : Parcelable
}
```